# How can I export file and folder tree structure of an external hard drive as a text file?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery

I have a malfunctioning hard drive that is full of thousands of files. All the files are still shown as 'there' when explored (with both Windows and Linux). Some of the files can be recovered by moving them to another hard drive, files with CRC errors cannot be moved.

Everything that can be recovered has been moved; the files that could not be moved have been left on the hard drive. I would like to create a 'text file' that lists all the files on the broken hard drive so that I have a list of files for future reference.

Are there any applications that allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Jimmy's suggestion, Windows dir command actually allows for a prettier output, this one gave me the best result:

```
dir *.mp3 /s /w /b > lostFiles.txt
```

Of course, removing *.mp3 from there gives all files, but in that case I only needed music.

Reference to dir command is here: http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `dir /s > fileList.txt`.  Not the prettiest output, but functional and definitely available on Windows.

Comment: Cheers! It works.